# what is wrong with mySQL query in my application?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have a main form (formMain) which loads a user control (classification) in its load event. And in the load event of the user control classification it displays a datagridview. Let me show you the code. 
**CLASSIFICATION**

```
string serverstring = "user id = root; password=; server=localhost; database=purchase_order; connection timeout=3;";

        private void load_data() 
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(serverstring);

            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM tblclassification";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);


                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = dt.TableName;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }    
        }
```

Luckily it's working but when I click the search button located in another user control (search) it raises an event in the main form (formMain) wherein it must FILTER the datagridview in the user control (classification) but my code is not working.
Maybe I have a syntax error in my string query. Here is the code.

**MAIN FORM**

```
void SearchClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Search content = _searchbox;
            classification control = new classification();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(serverstring);


            try
            {                
                string query = "SELECT * FROM tblclassification WHERE class_name LIKE '%@search'";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


                //MessageBox.Show(content.txtboxSearch.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", content.txtboxSearch.Text);


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);




                control.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                control.dataGridView1.DataMember = dt.TableName;


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }    
        }
```

Comment: Having an empty Catch doesn't help.

Comment: Did you want to look for class_name ending in the search text ?

Comment: @Habib Okay, in the Catch is it better to display the error message?

Answer (score 2):

use `CONCAT()`

```
string query = @"SELECT * 
                 FROM   tblclassification 
                 WHERE  class_name LIKE CONCAT('%', @search)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", content.txtboxSearch.Text);


MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: might be worth it to explain why :-)

Comment: I tried your code Sir but still it does not work. It does not filter the class_name.

Comment: see my updated answer. *Add a parameter before passing it on DataAdapter class*

Comment: or maybe you mean `WHERE  class_name LIKE CONCAT('%', @search, '%')`

Comment: The same Sir. I have a little concern in my code ->`control.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                control.dataGridView1.DataMember = dt.TableName;`, is that proper?

Comment: The reasoning for the concat is because while @search is inside the string, it won't be injected properly

Answer (score 0):

try

"SELECT * FROM purchase_order.tblclassification WHERE `class_name` LIKE ('%@search%')";

or ..

"SELECT * FROM `tblclassification` WHERE (`class_name` LIKE '%@search%')"

Comment: @JW you beat me to the punch :)

Comment: It's the same Sir, it does not filter the class_name. :(

Comment: what is the purpose of the '@' char,  try this format instead see edited answer